# Android.Java.Sqlite.Не находит столбец в таблице

Tags: java, android, sql, sqlite3

Не находит столбец в таблице  и выдаёт такую ошибку :

> android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: table information has no column named femaleWithName. Java - класс DBHelper :

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;


public class DBHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper{

    public static final int database_version = 1;
    public static final String database_name = "contactDb";
    public static final String table_contacts = "information";

    public static final String key_name = "name";
    public static final String key_female = "female";
    public static final String key_femaleWithName = "femaleWithName";


    public DBHelper(Context context) {
        super(context, database_name, null, database_version);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        db.execSQL(" create table " + table_contacts + " (  " + key_name + " varchar(30), " + key_female + " varchar(30),  " + key_femaleWithName + "   varchar(50)); "  );
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int i, int i1) {
        db.execSQL("drop table if exists " + table_contacts);

        onCreate(db);
    }
}
```

**Часть** класса в котором производятся действия с базой данных:

```
public class FindSome extends AppCompatActivity implements  IMassive{


    private ListView items;
    private AutoCompleteTextView search;

    private TextView result9,result13,result14,result15;

    private Button addbtm,rem;

    private String text;

    DBHelper dbHelper;

    SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase;
    ContentValues contentValues;

    private static final String TAG = "------LOGS------";
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_find_some);

        dbHelper = new DBHelper(this);



        result9 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView9);
        result13 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView13);
        result14 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView14);
        result15 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView15);

        list();
        Log.d(TAG," Запуск list()");
        ArrayAdapter adapt = new ArrayAdapter(this,android.R.layout.select_dialog_item,namespers);

        search = (AutoCompleteTextView)findViewById(R.id.searcher);
        search.setThreshold(0);
        search.setAdapter(adapt);

        addbtm = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button2);
        rem = (Button)findViewById(R.id.remove);

        rem.setOnClickListener(

                new View.OnClickListener(){
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v){
                        Intent intentremove = new Intent("com.example.x.myfirstnormal.ActivityRemove");
                        startActivity(intentremove);
                    }

                }
        );

        addbtm.setOnClickListener(

                new View.OnClickListener(){
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v){
                        Intent intentadd = new Intent("com.example.x.myfirstnormal.ActivityAdd");
                        startActivity(intentadd);
                    }

                }
        );

        items.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemClick (AdapterView<?> parent,
                              View view,
                              int position,
                              long id) {

                sqLiteDatabase  = dbHelper.getWritableDatabase();
                contentValues = new ContentValues();


                result9.setText("");
                result13.setText("");
                result14.setText("");
                result15.setText("");




                Cursor cursor = sqLiteDatabase.query(DBHelper.table_contacts,null,null,null,null,null,null);



                if(cursor.moveToFirst()){


                    int nameIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(DBHelper.key_name);
                    int femaleIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(DBHelper.key_female);
                    int nameAndFemaleIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(DBHelper.key_femaleWithName);



                    do{


                        String ifresult = cursor.getString(nameAndFemaleIndex);
                        String getResult = ifresult.replaceAll(" ", "");

                        if(getResult.equals(namespers.get(position).toString().replaceAll(" ", ""))){

                            result9.setText(cursor.getString(nameIndex));
                            result13.setText(cursor.getString(femaleIndex));

                        }
                    }while(cursor.moveToNext());
                }

               dbHelper.close();
            }
        });
    }
```

Как исправить ошибку?

P.S. Проект пробовал снести и заново запустить - не помогло .

Comment: Это всё здОрово, просто классно... а таблица-то в БД создаётся? а структура верная? перенесите удаление таблицы в OnCreate...

Comment: Помогло после перенесения ! Спасибо